# Error "Subscript out of range." on VBA Function

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

My question is, what could cause this error (Error "Subscript out of range.")? I'm running a function in VBA that reads data from a specific CSV that gets updated every minute. My function is:

```
Function CSVtoDataArray(CSVpath As String, fileName As String) As String()

Dim fnum As Integer
Dim whole_file As String
Dim lines As Variant
Dim one_line As Variant
Dim num_rows As Long
Dim the_array() As String
Dim file_path As String

whole_file = ""

file_path = CSVpath & fileName
' Load the file.
fnum = FreeFile
Open file_path For Input As fnum
whole_file = Input$(LOF(fnum), #fnum)
Close fnum

' Break the file into lines.'
lines = Split(whole_file, vbCrLf)
whole_file = ""
num_rows = UBound(lines)
the_array = Split(lines(num_rows - 1), ",")

CSVtoDataArray = the_array()

End Function
```

The error pops a while after my script started running, and the debug marks the error to reach these lines:

```
num_rows = UBound(lines)
the_array = Split(lines(num_rows - 1), ",")
```

This shows that my String `whole_file` is empty, giving a value of -1 to `num_rows`. Why do you think is the problem? And why does this error happens only after a while and not immediately?

Comment: Maybe because the loop reached an empty file? Don't empty your string `whole_file` before the error line, keep it so you can see if it's empty in the debugger.

Comment: Try using an `if` to check the value of the `UBound` or `Debug.Print` your `file_path` and `UBound`.  There might be a problem with your file, or as @A.S.H stated, you could just straight up be reaching an empty file.